# Can I set a global variable using the $GLOBALS array in PHP 8.1.0 and above?

Tags: php

I'm reading the PHP [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) for the $GLOBALS array, which says:

> As of PHP 8.1.0, write access to the entire $GLOBALS array is no
> longer supported

It also says:

> As of PHP 8.1.0, $GLOBALS is now a read-only copy of the global symbol
> table. That is, global variables cannot be modified via its copy.
> Previously, $GLOBALS array is excluded from the usual by-value
> behavior of PHP arrays and global variables can be modified via its
> copy.

I'm not sure what the above quotes mean, do they mean that I can't do the following?:

```
<?php
    $x = "hello";
    
    $GLOBALS["x"] = "bye";
    
    echo $x;
?>
```

Comment: The obvious thing to do, is to try it. This is in PHP version 8.1.16: https://3v4l.org/d0b5Y#v8.1.16 But if you worry about your own PHP version, just execute the script and you'll know.

Comment: @KIKO Software It worked, but it can work and still be deprecated I guess.

Comment: No, I think what they're saying is that you're no longer allowed to assign a new value to the whole `$GLOBALS` array.

Comment: _"I'm not sure what the above quotes mean"_ - there's explicit _examples_ given below what you quoted, how excatly are those unclear?

Answer (score 2):

Prior to PHP version `8.1.0` you could assign a value to the entire `$GLOBALS` array ([3v4l](https://3v4l.org/WlPOC#v8.0.0)):

```php
$GLOBALS = "Test";

echo $GLOBALS; // Would echo 'Test' prior to PHP 8.1.0
```

In every more recent PHP version, you will get a fatal error ([3v4l](https://3v4l.org/WlPOC#v8.1.0)):

> Fatal error: $GLOBALS can only be modified using the $GLOBALS[$name] = $value syntax.

As the error message suggests, you may still assign a value using the array syntax.

```php
$GLOBALS["myVar"] = "Test";

echo $GLOBALS["myVar"]; // Will echo 'Test'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a consequence of the [Restrict $GLOBALS usage RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/restrict_globals_usage).

The proposal states:

> Accesses of the form `$GLOBALS[$var]` will refer to the global variable `$$var`, and support all the usual variable operations, including writes. `$GLOBALS[$var] = $value` remains supported. A good way to think of this is that `$GLOBALS[$var]` works the same way as a variable-variable `$$var`, just accessing the global instead of the local scope.

and later explicitly confirms that `$GLOBALS['x'] = 1;` should continue to work.  However, it is now a special case, and `$GLOBALS` can no longer, in general, be used with operations that would modify it in place:

```php
function set(&$array, $key, $val) {
    $array[$key] = $val;
}

$arr = ['x' => 0];

set($arr, 'x', 1);        // works
set($GLOBALS, 'x', 1);    // no longer works as of PHP 8.1
```